# Defining variable for VLOOKUP code

Tags: vba, excel

Have been trying to run a sample code but unable to do so. most proabably because I did not define the variables properly( Table 1&2 and Cl) .Could anyone help me rectify it so i have a better idea on how i should do it in the future?Thanks alot. Here is the code

```
Option Explicit


Sub ADDCLM()
On Error Resume Next
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Dim Table1 As Range
Dim Table2 As Range
Dim cl As Variant

Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A3:A13") ' Employee_ID Column from Employee table
Table2 = Sheet1.Range("H3:I13") ' Range of Employee Table 1
Dept_Row = Sheet1.Range("E3").Row ' Change E3 with the cell from where you need to start populating the Department
Dept_Clm = Sheet1.Range("E3").Column
For Each cl In Table1
  Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you not only aren't properly setting ranges (as KS Sheon already pointed out) but you are also using invalid reference: `Sheet1` should be substituted with `Worksheets("Sheet1")`

furthermore the code can be as simplified as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub ADDCLM()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E13").FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC1,R3C8:R13C9,2,False)"
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

or, if you want to keep values only in E3:E13

```
Option Explicit

Sub ADDCLM2()

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E13")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC1,R3C8:R13C9,2,False)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: i Would like to incorporate ISNA Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E13").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(Vlookup(RC1,R3C8:R8C9,2,False))," - ",RC1)" but i am getting a type mismatch error

Comment: Use "" - "" instead of " - "

Comment: Isit possible to implement this formula across different sheets. Eg. I am vlooking up from another sheet instead of the same sheet.

Comment: I'm not by my PC and can't remember if VLookup handles references to worksheets other than the cell one. But I suppose it does. Just google it and check it. Were it the case you just have to add proper reference before the RC's  (like "'Some Other Sheet'!R3C8:R8C9")

Answer (score 1):

table1 and table2 are declared as range "object". to assign a value to an "object" you have to use `set`, i.e.

```
set Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A3:A13")`
set Table2 = Sheet1.Range("H3:I13")
```

you don't need to use `set` for Dept_Row and Dept_clm because they are merely assigned a "value".

`cl` should be declared as range, because of you are calling `For Each cl In Table1`.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you. The only change that were needed was to update the Table1 and Table2 to Variant types or use Set before Table1 and Table2. This is defined in the syntax for the the following [Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx) expression.

```
'Option 1 Declare Tables as vaiants
Option Explicit


Sub ADDCLM()
On Error Resume Next
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Dim Table1 As Variant
Dim Table2 As Variant
Dim cl As Variant

Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A3:A13") ' Employee_ID Column from Employee table
Table2 = Sheet1.Range("H3:I13") ' Range of Employee Table 1
Dept_Row = Sheet1.Range("E3").Row ' Change E3 with the cell from where you need to start populating the Department
Dept_Clm = Sheet1.Range("E3").Column
For Each cl In Table1
  Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Or: '

```
'Option 2 Set Ranges using "Set"
Option Explicit


Sub ADDCLM()
On Error Resume Next
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Dim Table1 As Range
Dim Table2 As Range
Dim cl As Variant


Set Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A3:A13") ' Employee_ID Column from Employee table
Set Table2 = Sheet1.Range("H3:I13") ' Range of Employee Table 1
Dept_Row = Sheet1.Range("E3").Row ' Change E3 with the cell from where you need to start populating the Department
Dept_Clm = Sheet1.Range("E3").Column
For Each cl In Table1
  Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a application defined /object defined error

Comment: when i used variant, it is an object required error

Comment: where are you pasting this? in the code behind the sheet or a module?

Comment: it is behind a sheet

Comment: Nope! I tried pasting it in the module but i am getting an error on this line

Comment: Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)

Comment: What is the name of the Tab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107510/discussion-between-tyler-furrer-and-niva).

Comment: I am still getting the same error on the same line.